# How to convert RA-Dec coordinates to galactic coordinates in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, astropy, fits

I was converting a pixel coordinate fits file to world coordinates in Python. The header shows that this fits file is in RA-Dec coordinate system . I want to convert this to galactic coordinates. Here is what I've tried.

```
from astropy import coordinates as coord
from astropy import units as u
c=coord.icrscoord(ra=wx,dec=wy,unit=(u.degree,u.degree))
c.galactic

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'icrscoord'
```

This does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's no such thing as `astropy.coordinates.icrscoord`.  The `AttributeError` means you're trying to use something that doesn't exist.  Where did you get the idea it would?  The closest thing is `ICRS`, but you wouldn't typically use that directly over `SkyCoord`: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/index.html

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Astropy documentation](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/), the syntax is:

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
c = SkyCoord(ra=wx*u.degree, dec=wy*u.degree, frame='icrs')
c.galactic
```

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK.THE RESULT OF THIS CODE IS AS FOLLOWS<SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    (272.24883058, -20.11923193)>                                                                              I need result in the Galactic coordinates.This gves result in the  Ra-Dec Coordinates

Comment: @LALI No, @HBouy's answer is correct.  You missed the last step.  `c = SkyCoord(ra=wx*u.degree, dec=wy*u.degree, frame='icrs')` creates a `SkyCoord` *object* from your coordinates in RA-Dec.  You can that use this object to query things about the coordinates, as well as convert it to other representations.  `c.galactic` gives you a copy of the same point on the sky but in galactic coordinates.